# How Data sent over network?

Tags: networking, send, packets, transmission

How the data is actually sent over the network.
I know it is transmitted in Hex but is the raw hex equivalent for the data sent?

I mean if i wanted to send a simple ASCII text "hello" , is the hex equivalent of 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' is sent or does it do any encoding or encryption.

also would it do 'zip' kind of thing.. i mean would it find the 2 'l's in "hello" and some way send any equivalent for that?

Comment: Sorry, what? Maybe this helps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_1:_physical_layer

Answer (score 3):

It is not sent in hex. It is sent in binary. Period. No encoding. No encryption. No zipping. What you send is what it sends.

Comment: @slebetman The point of your comment escapes me. The OP didn't say anything about words, and neither did I.

Comment: I was generalizing what you said. In computers, there is no such thing as a "string". The string "hello" is merely a piece of binary data that we choose to interpret in such a way that represents the word "hello" to us. It could also be interpreted as a single 40-bit number. The computer doesn't care. All there is is binary. Everything else is how we choose to interpret things.

Comment: FWIW, the ASCII string "hello" if interpreted as a 40-bit number is four hundred and forty eight billion, three hundred and seventy eight million, two hundred and three thousand, two hundred forty seven (448378203247 or 0x68656c6c6f).